# Generating a list of prime numbers in Python

Tags: python

I  am using this code to get a list of prime numbers up to an integer 'x' but I am not sure where I am wrong.

```
from math import sqrt

def prime_detector(x):
    for i in range(3, x+1):
        numbers = []
        Status = True
        for j in range(2, int(sqrt(i)+1)+1):
            if i%j == 0:
                Status = False
        if Status == True:
            numbers += [i]
    return numbers

print(prime_detector(20))
```

Comment: Please provide your error message and fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. For debugging questions, you need to provide a [mre]. In this case you should use a descriptive title and add the expected output vs actual output, though we can infer the problem. You can [edit] the question. Check out [ask] if you want other advice.

Comment: BTW you can use `all` to simplify: `if all(i%j != 0 for j in range(2, int(sqrt(i)+1)+1)): numbers += [i]`

Answer (score 1):

Move number outside for and it will work

```
from math import sqrt
def prime_detector(x):
    numbers = []
    for i in range(3, x+1):
        Status = True
        for j in range(2, int(sqrt(i)+1)+1):
            if i % j == 0:
                Status = False
                break
        if Status == True:
            numbers += [i]
    return numbers
print(prime_detector(20))
```

Comment: Thank you! got it.

Answer (score 0):

Move number object is inside the for loop and the scope of object matters:) for and it will work

```
from math import sqrt
def prime_detector(x):
    numbers = []
    for i in range(3, x+1):
        Status = True
        for j in range(2, int(sqrt(i)+1)+1):
            if i % j == 0:
                Status = False
                break
        if Status == True:
            numbers += [i]
    return numbers
print(prime_detector(20))
```

The above code has one more problem:- 2 is a prime number and we are not going to take care of that case.
So if you want to include the 2 in your list just Make it as:-
`number = [2]` in above code.

And if you want to improve it more than use step as 6, and check the condition with j and j+2. It will give you a more optimal solution.